# How to find element by <span> without class or title in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get some text inner span tag, but span tag does not have any class or title.
**Its just like:**

```
<span>kirnath@me.com</span>
<span>kirnath2@me.com</span>
<span>kirnath3@me.com</span>
```

**I have tried using:**

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), 'kirnath@me.com')]')
```

**But I got error:**

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(text(), kirnath@me.com)]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

**I need to get:**

```
kirnath@me.com    
kirnath2@me.com   
kirnath3@me.com
```

Comment: Can we see more html?

Comment: Use double quotes outisde xpath and simple inside xpath: "//*[contains(text(), 'kirnath@me.com')]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all spans then grab the webElements list and use list comprehension to extract the .text from each into a list. If you don't want all spans, look for a relationship/positional argument for example that limits to those required. Or possibly even substring match on .text if you have a consistently present substring to use.

```
span_texts = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span')]
```

xpath substring

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "me.com")]')
```

---

You could use :contains pseudo class from bs4 4.7.1 to handle the html from driver.page_source. You can then specify a substring to match on for the span tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

data = [item.text for item in soup.select('span:contains("@me.com")')]
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:  !?

```
inp="bla <span>kirnath@me.com</span> blub"

p1=inp.find("<span>")
p2=inp.find("</span>")
if p1>=0 and p2>p1:
  print(inp[p1+len("<span>"):p2])
```

output is:

```
kirnath@me.com
```

**Edit:** or like this for more matches

```
inp="bla <span>kirnath@me.com</span><span>kirnath2@me.com</span><span>kirnath3@me.com</span> blub"

def find_all(inp):
  res=[]
  p=0
  while True:
    p1=inp.find("<span>", p)
    p2=inp.find("</span>", p)
    if p1>=0 and p2>p1:
      res+=[inp[p1+len("<span>"):p2]]
      p=p2+1
    else:
      return res

print(find_all(inp))
```

output is:

```
['kirnath@me.com', 'kirnath2@me.com', 'kirnath3@me.com']
```

Comment: i have lot of span tag, <span>kirnath@me.com</span> <span>kirnath2@me.com</span> <span>kirnath3@me.com</span>

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotation for both the inner quotation inside a string and outside of the string. use the double quotation for the text inside. Or use the backslash before the quotation.

Try this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "kirnath@me.com")]')
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), \'kirnath@me.com\')]')
```

This will only return the element with the text `kirnath@me.com`.

To find any email address you can use

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "@") and contains(text(), ".")]')
```

This will find all the elements that contain text with `@` and `.`

Getting all the span element of the page is not ideal. Even though the `span` tag doesn't have any id or class, its parent nodes might have some unique identifier.

Can you provide the page source with some levels of parent nodes?